# Symfony2: Doctrine.... [Semantical Error] line 0, col 17 near 'Logs l': Error: Class 'Logs' is not defined

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm breaking my head.... why this error????
    [Semantical Error] line 0, col 17 near 'Logs l': Error: Class 'Logs' is not defined.

this is my code:

```
<?php
namespace Alex\DatabaseBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * LogsRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class LogsRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getLatestlogs()
    {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $qb = $em->createQuery('SELECT l.id FROM Logs l');
        return $qb->getResult();

    }    
}
```

i dont understand.....
i'm new, but i'm blocked to this simple situation....

Comment: You need to use the full namespace. Either `FROM AlexDatabaseBundle:Logs` or `FROM Alex\Entity\Logs`

Comment: How do you call this function? What do you have in your entity mapping?

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVED!!

Thank you Touki

```
FROM AlexDatabaseBundle:Logs
```

has worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your repository instead, or you need to use a full namespace path `SELECT l.id FROM \Acme\YourBundle\Entity\Logs l`

```
class LogsRepository extends EntityRepository
{

   public function getLatestlogs()
   {
       $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->select('l.id')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
   }    
}
```